# hide div on click other part of page using element id

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, click, enter

In my website I have many search boxes. I use javascript to hide the search result when click outside on those results. For that I use the below code

```
$(document).click(function (e) {

    if (!$(e.target).is('#elem1, #elem2, #elem3, #elem4, #elem5')) {
        $("#elem1").hide();
        $("#elem1").html("");
        $("#elem2").hide();
        //$("#elem3").hide();
        $("#elem4").show();
        $("#elem5").show();
    }
});
```

the search field is

```
<form name="form-name">
    <input type="text" value="" id="search-field" />
    <button value="search" id="search-button">
</form>
```

the search list is

```
<div id="id1">
    <ul>
    <li>data2</li>
    <li>data3</li>
    <li>data4</li>
    <li>data5</li>
     <li>data6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and I identify the `enter` press via the below code

```
$("#search-field").keyup(TriggeredFunction);

function TriggeredFunction(e) {
e = e || window.event;
var keycode;
if (window.event) {
    keycode = e.which ? window.event.which : window.event.keyCode;
}
var key = e.which;
switch (key) {
    case 13:
        //action code
        break;
    default: 
        //default code
}
}
```

This code worked perfectly. And the click event on the `li` works prefect. But once I tried to write a function which invoke when I press `enter` key. That `enter` press invoked the above `$(document).click()` function (This time also the `click` on `li` works fine). So that the search result become empty. I was fetching the data from the search result. Because of this, I can't fetch the data. Is there any way to prevent this? Please help

Comment: Just thinking can't you create a global variable and then in `TriggeredFunction` function set some certain value in it and then in `$(document).click(function (e)` check if that variable has that certain value, then do not empty the search result?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off stopping the event bubbling on the search field.

In JQuery:

```
$( "#search-field, #search-button" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

In vanilla JavaScript:

```
if(event.stopPropagation) {
    event.stopPropagation();
} else {
    event.cancelBubble = true;
}
```